# Render local DEM on NASA world wind

Tags: algorithm, rendering, terrain, worldwind, tesselation

I am trying to render a local elevation data on World Wind. And then use the world wind's tessellation algorithm to tessellate the data and render it on the globe. 
I know about the LocalElevationModel. and I was able to store a DEM file using this:

```
    LocalElevationModel localElevationModel = new LocalElevationModel();
    String filepath = "";
    localElevationModel.addElevations(filepath);
```

I can access this model using the lookupElevation method over the max,min lat log from the localElevation data. But I don't know how to proceed forward. I have looked into the RectangularTessellator class but couldn't understand how to use it.
Any clues on how I can do this?

PS:I was looking at their source code but couldn't understand much to make much scene out of it. So I wanted to know more about it.

PPS: If not possible can someone guide me to an easy to implement and optimized algorithm for rendering of the terrain. Which supports various LODs of the generated mess.

Thanks,